# How do I set return_uri for GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) in my **non-MVC .NET Web Application**. (This appears to be an important distinction.)

I’ve tried to use code from [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) at Google and [this example](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) at Daimto along with some helpful hints from a number of [related posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669497/google-calendar-api-authentication-net-browser-window).

I have written the following method:

```
public void GetUserCredential( String userName )
{
    String clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "Google.ClientId" ];            //From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
    String clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "Google.ClientSecret" ];    //From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
    String[] scopes = new string[] {
            Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.Calendar          
    };

    // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret             
    }, scopes, userName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore( "c:\\temp" ) ).Result;

    // TODO: Replace FileDataStore with DatabaseDataStore
}
```

Problem is, when Google’s OAuth2 page is called, `redirect_uri` keeps getting set to `http://localhost:<some-random-port>/authorize`. I have no idea how to set this to something else, as in the following example URL generated by `AuthorizeAsync`:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline
    &response_type=code
    &client_id=********.apps.googleusercontent.com
    &redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:40839%2Fauthorize%2F
    &scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar
```

Google responds with a **redirect_uri_mismatch** error page with the message:

“The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:XXXXX/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI”

I can only register so many Redirect URI’s in my Google Developer’s Console Credentials page. I’m not inclined to register 65535 ports, and I want to use a page other than `/authorize` on my site. Specifically, I want to use, during development, `http://localhost:888/Pages/GoogleApiRedirect` but have no clue as to where I would set this, beyond what I've done in the Developer’s Console.

How do I explicitly set the value of `redirect_uri`? I am also open to a response in the form “This approach is completely wrong.”

**EDIT:**

After playing with this over the past day, I've discovered that by using the Client ID/Client Secret for the Native Application rather than the Web Application, I can at least get to Google's web authorization page without it complaining about a **redirect_uri_mismatch**. This is still unacceptable, because it still returns to `http://localhost:<some-random-port>/authorize`, which is outside the control of my web application.

Comment: Have you tried configuring visual studio to use a predefined port for your web app project? check this documentation, so you can define a port and use it in your developer console. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Gerardo. Yes, it's already preconfigured for port 888. I've also tried "unprivileged" ports above 1024. I've seen this suggestion in a few situations that are similar to mine. If it did work, I suppose I could live with `/authorize` being my redirect page. Not an ideal solution, but one I could live with.

Comment: You could also try to deploy the project directly in IIS,  from there you can have more control on the port for your web app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465323(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Another good suggestion, @Gerardo. Thing is, `redirect_uri` is just a *parameter* for goodness sake! Why is it being arbitrarily and uncontrollably set as it is? I'm both surprised and frustrated by the utter lack of documentation on this issue. Which leads me to wonder, as I've posed towards the end of my question, if I'm approaching this entirely incorrectly and I should not be using `AuthorizeAsync` at all.

Comment: @Peter - I've tested both on my dev machine (`localhost:888`) and on my beta machine `beta.??????.com` and the example below works well on both.

Comment: @BobKaufman Great, have you had any challenges with LocalServerCodeReceiver throwing a Win32 unauthorised exception? seems to want to open up some sort of port which under IIS Express works, but the minute i host in IIS it doesnt have the right IIS permissions.  If you look at the code under google-api-dotnet-client/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs there is some funky stuff going on with trying to find unused ports etc.

Comment: @Peter - not yet. At the moment, I'm just too busy being thrilled that it seamlessly adds and reads things from my one calendar. But that is likely to change over the next few days. As I'm in this code, I'll be paying particular attention to your comment.

Comment: @BobKaufman i tried using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker and deep down in the code base is causes a failure in a class called LocalServerCode Receiver where IIS attempts to call Process.Run(url). The problem is that IIS doesnt have permission to access Process.Run() whilst IISExpress does because it is running as a user account. Interesting that you do not have this problem... I am having issues on my Windows 10 machine with IIS installed. I think GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker might be for standard applications not for web applications - well not under the standard IIS configuration.

Comment: @BobKaufman: issue at https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/611#issuecomment-147771019

Comment: The problem for me now is that I don't receive user credentials after successful authentication. I think something similar to @PiotrStulinski. If I use desktop application (with slightly different code than below), user credentials return to method public Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value) and are stored in T value. With method below I receive response to my return uri, but no credentials. Method StoreAsync is never called.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this code: (original idea from http://coderissues.com/questions/27512300/how-to-append-login-hint-usergmail-com-to-googlewebauthorizationbroker)

```
dsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri = "my localhost redirect uri";
UserCredential credential = await dsAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...
```

dsAuthorizationBroker.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace OAuth2
{    
    public class dsAuthorizationBroker : GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
    {
        public static string RedirectUri;

        public new static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(
            ClientSecrets clientSecrets,
            IEnumerable<string> scopes,
            string user,
            CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
            IDataStore dataStore = null)
        {
            var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
            };
            return await AuthorizeAsyncCore(initializer, scopes, user,
                taskCancellationToken, dataStore).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsyncCore(
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer,
            IEnumerable<string> scopes,
            string user,
            CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
            IDataStore dataStore)
        {
            initializer.Scopes = scopes;
            initializer.DataStore = dataStore ?? new FileDataStore(Folder);
            var flow = new dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
            return await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, 
                new LocalServerCodeReceiver())
                .AuthorizeAsync(user, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }


    public class dsAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    {
        public dsAuthorizationCodeFlow(Initializer initializer)
            : base(initializer) { }

        public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
                       CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
        {
            return base.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(dsAuthorizationBroker.RedirectUri);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really help at all. nothing is explained... simply waving a magic wand and making it work in some arcane and inscrutable way doesn't really answer the original question, which is "why doesn't the original code work?"

Comment: I don't think that this answer helps. Nowhere is the RedirectUri actually set.

Comment: Thanks for this help. But one issue, not close authentication window . How to close this authendicaton window and then redirect to current working project page?

Comment: This does not return a TOKEN! I posted a reply to hopefully help people past this problem.

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync in a .NET application NON-web server application i.e. C# Console App command line program, it's crucial when creating the Google OAuth profile (https://console.developers.google.com/apis) in the credentials to select the following.

**DESKTOP APP** - This also known now as an installed application

It's hidden under "Help me choose" new credential. You must create a new credential which shows Desktop app and not WebApp.

#### CLICK "HELP ME CHOOSE"

[image: Step 1]

#### CHOOSE YOUR INTENDED API LIBRARY

ie (Google Calendar API, YouTube) Select "User Data"

[image: Step2]

#### STEP 3 - OAUTH CLIENT ID - Desktop App!

[image: Step3]

#### Yeah - NO AUTHORIZATION REQUIRED FILEDS"

ie Javascript & Redirect Now you have a profile without the Web Application redirect authorization

[image]

#### Use the "Download JSON" and save it to your application

Reference in the code below. When you look inside this file, you will notice a different set of parameters as well to tell the broker this is an application. In this example, I am accessing the scope Calendar API. Just change the scope to whatever API you are trying to access.**

```
string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }; //requires full scope to get ACL list..

string ApplicationName = "Name Of Your Application In Authorization Screen";
//just reference the namespaces in your using block
        
using (var stream = new FileStream("other_client_id.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
   {
   // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
    // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
   string credPath = "other_token.json";
   credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
      Scopes,
      "user",
      CancellationToken.None,
      new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;               
    }
        
// Create Google Calendar API service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
   ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});
        
//Then your ready to grab data from here using the methods mentioned in Google Calendar API docs
```

### To run this in Docker

When you deploy this to docker you will get an exception that the operating system does not support running the process. Basically, its trying to open a browser on the Metal Box. which is not possible with docker.

To solve this. Modify the code to use full absolute path like this

```
var inputFolderAbsolute = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Auth.Store");
...
new FileDataStore(inputFolderAbsolute, true)
```

- Run this application as a console app on your local machine so the browser opens.
- Select the account you want to work with
- In the bin folder, a new folder and file will be created.
- Copy that folder to the root path
- Set the file to copy if newer
- Deploy to docker
- Because the refresh token is saved for the account you selected it will get a new access token and work.
- NB: It is possible the refresh token expires to whatever reason. You will have to repeat the steps above

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you so much for this hidden reply. Helped me out yesterday.

Comment: I don't have an option "Where you will be calling the API from?".... Solution doesn't work or outdated...

Comment: I tried this and got the following error in my Windows desktop app: 
`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse` Can you help?

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you for taking us through this. I did update it as Google changes it a little bit. Essentially what we need to do for console applications is use the "Installed credential" For Desktop Applications.  The "redirect" part Just works now and I get an access token AND a refresh token! Thanks again

Comment: This actually worked (for GDrive). Very nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling to build a console app that would be able to authenticate to Gmail to send mail, here is what worked. `LocalServerCodeReceiver` was the key to listening to access token returned from the browser. This code also would obtain a refresh token if needed, and will cache the token on the file system for future use.

```
var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = YOUR_CLIENTID,
    ClientSecret = YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
};

var codeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    DataStore = new FileDataStore(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory),
    Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom },
    ClientSecrets = clientSecrets
});

var codeReceiver = new LocalServerCodeReceiver();
var authCode = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(codeFlow, codeReceiver);
var credential = await authCode.AuthorizeAsync(EmailUser, CancellationToken.None);

if (authCode.ShouldRequestAuthorizationCode(credential.Token))
{
    await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Note:

- in my experience, Firefox didn't handle the browser redirect correctly, so I had to switch my default Windows browser to Chrome in order for this to work
- even though this code is part of a console app, it is not entirely set up to run unattended; unless the token is cached on the filesystem from prior runs, you would need to manually go through the authentication flow in the browser popup
- the OAuth client ID configuration in the Developers console should be set to "Desktop"

Comment: Thanks for the hint with "Desktop" basically means it acts like an installed app as described in Google Documents. Updated @moto_geek answer on how to generate a desktop token and it just works as per the Google document, in a C# console app

Answer (score 2):

selecting "other" while creating oAuth Client ID helped me resolve the redirection issue for me. (Having the "Web Application" option tries to redirect to some url with random port, which is very annoying)

Now my Gmail API works like a charm :)