# Google+ sign in return uri not found

Tags: .net, google-plus, google-signin

I am using VS2015, MVC5 application.

When trying to sign in with google, I receive:  Error: redirect_uri_mismatch.

My code:

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  new ClientSecrets
  {
  ClientId = "client_id",
  ClientSecret = "client_secret"
  },
  new[] { PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile,
                    PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin, PlusService.Scope.PlusMe},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None, new AuthStorage(_cookie));
```

I've set return uri in google developer console:

https://localhost:44314/signin.ashx

If I try and type in this uri in the browser, it works fine. I don't understand why google plus doesn't find it?

**EDIT:**

After days of researching I've finally found this, which solved my problem:

[How do I set return_uri for GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209273/how-do-i-set-return-uri-for-googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect\_uri\_mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485271/google-oauth-2-authorization-error-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: I've found this before, but it didn't helped me. What helped me I've posted in my edit.