# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker failed to launch browser with https //accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth; redirect uri mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have the exact same issue as in this question:
[How do I set return_uri for GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209273/how-do-i-set-return-uri-for-googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync)

However, that question was answered 3 years ago and the answer provided isn't working for me; I see no way to actually set the redirect uri. So here's the issue:

```
static async Task<UserCredential> GetCredential()
{

    var clientSecretPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "client_secret.json";
    var credPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "credentials/GoogleAnalyticsApiConsole/";

    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretPath,
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var secrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets;


        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            new[] {AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics},
            "analytics@mysite.com", 
            CancellationToken.None, 
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true));

        return credential;
    }
}
```

This is returning the following error:

```
failed to launch browser with https //accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
```

It's trying to launch the oauth2 page with redirect_uri = "http://localhost:/authorize"; when I try to directly view the url it's trying to launch, the page says "The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:XXXXX/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI"

I tried just adding localhost:XXXXX to the authorized urls in the Google API Console, but the next time I ran it the port was different, like localhost:XXXYY. My client_secret.json file has all of the authorized redirect urls listed, but aren't being used. How do I set the redirect uri and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to build a locally installed application or a asp.net web application, but based on the question you have pointed to, i assume its a web application and here's how i solved it.

First of all, GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker's default implementation is for locally installed application. You can find its implementation in this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs) 
.As a result your code might work fine in your local machine but when hosted in webserver it might load forever.

So you need to implement your own AuthorizationCodeFlow for Web applications as mentioned in the google's documentation.

And this is how i implemented it in my **ASP.NET Core MVC** web application

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfigureGA(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            GoogleAnalyticsModel model = new GoogleAnalyticsModel();
            var state = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request);
            var result = await GetCredential(state, cancellationToken);
            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                using (var svc = new AnalyticsService(
                    new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Your App Name"
                    }))
                {

                    ManagementResource.AccountSummariesResource.ListRequest list = svc.Management.AccountSummaries.List();
                    list.MaxResults = 1000;
                    AccountSummaries feed = await list.ExecuteAsync();
                    model.UserAccounts = feed.Items.ToList();
                }

                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }

        }    
private async Task<AuthorizationCodeWebApp.AuthResult> GetCredential(string state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var userId = userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Id;
            var redirectUri = Request.Scheme + "://" + Request.Host.ToUriComponent() + "/authcallback/";
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json",
                 FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly, AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
                    DataStore = datastore
                });

                return await new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, redirectUri, state)
                        .AuthorizeAsync(userId, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
```

I am passing the state of the application while requesting oauth credential(i.e., GetCredential() method).

In this method, create your own IAuthorizationCodeFlow and pass your flow, redirect_uri(which you must also set in your Google Developer Console) and the state of your application to **AuthorizationCodeWebApp**

Next you must implement the **authcallback** controller to handle the oauth code. This code is similar to the google-dotnet-client library [found here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc/OAuth2/Mvc/Controllers/AuthCallbackController.cs) but i have adopted the same code because i am working with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

```
public class AuthCallbackController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly IGoogleAnalyticsDataStore datastore;

        public AuthCallbackController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IGoogleAnalyticsDataStore datastore)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.datastore = datastore;
        }

        protected virtual ActionResult OnTokenError(TokenErrorResponse errorResponse)
        {
            throw new TokenResponseException(errorResponse);
        }
        public async virtual Task<ActionResult> Index(AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl authorizationCode,
            CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json",
                 FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            DataStore = datastore,
            Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly, AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly }
        });

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationCode.Code))
                {
                    var errorResponse = new TokenErrorResponse(authorizationCode);

                    return OnTokenError(errorResponse);
                }
                string userId = userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Id;
                var returnUrl = UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl(Request);

                var token = await flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(userId, authorizationCode.Code, returnUrl.Substring(0, returnUrl.IndexOf("?")),
                    taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Extract the right state.
                var oauthState = await AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(datastore, userId,
                    authorizationCode.State).ConfigureAwait(false);

                return new RedirectResult(oauthState);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this answers your question and a little beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem today.
It turned out that there was **no "default" Program** set for handling http/https protocol.

[image]