# How to update users Gmail signature

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, asp.net-core-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using ASP .Net Core 2 with Google Authentication.  I'm needing update the email signature (gmail). But I dont know how can I take the Google Credential (after the authentication).

I have a problem with the url port, all the time generate a another port - ex.: localhost:4550, another time localhost:3568 (I cant unlock the correct url in Google Console because that). I tried this one: stackoverflow.com/questions/31209273/… but in my server, when I click on the button, dont open the popup,

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
            {
                googleOptions.ClientId = googleClientId;
                googleOptions.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
            });
```

Im trying this code too:

```
        UserCredential cred = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                              new ClientSecrets
                              {
                                  ClientId = _applicationSettings.GoogleClientId,
                                  ClientSecret = _applicationSettings.GoogleClientSecret
                              },
                              scopes,
                              "me",
                              CancellationToken.None,
                              new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store"));
```

but I have another problems and this code doesn't work. Someone know how can I implement this?? Thanks.

Comment: @Tseng I can do this with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209273/how-do-i-set-return-uri-for-googlewebauthorizationbroker-authorizeasync/32119401 But this code dont work. In localhost the page dont receive the authentication confirmation (waiting so much time), and in the server dont open the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The Google .net client library does not support Asp .net Core currently."

Then, Im using aspcore authentication with Google services, and some permissions:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        })
        .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
        {
            options.AccessType = "offline";
            options.ClientId = googleClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.Scope.Add(GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom);
            options.Scope.Add(GmailService.Scope.GmailSettingsBasic);
        });
```

And in my Controller, Im getting the Token for to do a REST and update the signature:

```
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   var externalAccessToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "Google", "access_token");
```

REST format:

PUT https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs/ + "useremaillogged"

Header Authorization Bearer "your token"

Json Object

{
"signature":"your signature"
}

Answer (score 0):

The Google .net client libary does not currently support authencation with Asp .Net core.  the code you are using

```
UserCredential cred = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                          new ClientSecrets
                          {
                              ClientId = _applicationSettings.GoogleClientId,
                              ClientSecret = _applicationSettings.GoogleClientSecret
                          },
                          scopes,
                          "me",
                          CancellationToken.None,
                          new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store"));
```

Is for authenticating installed applications like console applications where the browser window is opened on the machine the code is running on.   With web applications the authentication needs to open the browser authencation window on the client machine.  There is currently no way of doing this with the .Net Client library.

please see issue [933](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/933) and [1109](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/1109) and [1151](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1151)

Comment: How can I get "result.Credential" on aspcore?

Comment: var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = **result.Credential**,
                    ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                });

Comment: Yes, this code is for Asp.net MVC and Im using Aspcore 2. Im tring here, but dont have support to Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc and System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: I added it as an issue see what happends https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1151

Comment: Thanks for your help @DalmTo 
Im tring use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow, but the AspCore dont have suport for after this code:

var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

Comment: The Google .net client library does not support Asp .net Core currently you cant authenticate with it.