# google oAuth trying to redirect to random uri different from my app url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

It's a .Net Core2.1 webApplication , c#.
Targeting to sync my contacts with google people API.

I have a front end application that will grant permission from an end user and get me an access token.

when starting the sync flow,oAuth returns an error even before reaching the set token step.

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

My app url is http://localhost:58240.

while on each authentication request to the app, the url proivded with the error,and stated as unauthorized, is different from 58240. and it CHANGES with each request

Note  that :
1- Enable SSl is off.
2- Auto-generates binding redirect is set to No.

```
UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
           new ClientSecrets
           {
               ClientId = this._client_id,
               ClientSecret = this._client_secret
           },
              new[] { "profile", this.scope_readOnly },
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32119401/5717681 for exact Problem/Solution ,

Answer (score 0):

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

means exactly that you are sending from a redirect uri which you have not added in google developer console.  There should be a button on the error screen where you can see exactly what URL you are sending from.  Take that url and added it Google developer console

It will probably end in `AuthCallback`

```
https://localhost:44323/AuthCallback/
```

You will need to set up your dev environment to NOT apply random ports you need a static port to be able to set the redirect uri properly in Google developer console.

Comment: Nop, the problem is that the port after the localhost keeps changing. so nothing can be set from the authorization side.

Comment: I answered the question myself. it seemed it was already asked but i couldn't find it before.

Comment: Read my last line. You need to stop the port from changing. So that you can set the redirect uri properly.   I have marked your question duplicate since you say that it helped you.

Comment: I am using colab notebooks, how to set fixed port for that?