# How to set AccessType as offline in Google.Apis.Core 1.9 in C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google APIs for OAuth2 version 1.9 and trying to send AccessType as offline and ApprovalPrompt as force everytime so that I get a refresh token. I know there are many questions on this topic here in various api versions and languages. However, none of the solutions works with the new google library.

I am using the following to get the flow:

```
private IAuthorizationCodeFlow GetAuthorizationCodeFlow()
        {
            var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId =
                            "***",
                        ClientSecret = "***"
                    },

                    Scopes = new string[]
                                 {
                                     CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
                                     PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile,
                                     PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
                                     PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
                                     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"
                                 }
                });

            return flow;            
        }
```

and then using the following code to get the token:

```
var token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("me", code,
                    uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")), CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

This is where I need the refresh token every time (not just the first time) so I want to set the AccessType and ApprovalPrompt.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The library automatically stores the refresh token for your users in order to refresh their access token when it expires. What exactly do you try to achieve by setting access type to offline?

Comment: We are not using the library storage mechanism. We were using the old library and upgrading to v3. We store the refresh token in a database field and use it to get the access token every time. So, when the refresh token is not there or if the call fails, we want to authenticate and get the refresh token again. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you want your users to authenticate again in order to get refresh token (and access token as well), you don't need to do anything. Just upgrade your library and the users will have to authenticate as the first step. If you want to upgrade the library using the OLD REFRESH TOKEN, that's a different story. What scenario of the two, do you want to support?

Comment: We can force users to authenticate again by making the refresh token null in the database. That is not the issue. I am looking for the flexibility to get the refresh token any time we want. The default behavior is that once the refresh token is sent, it will not be sent again for the lifetime of the refresh token and null will be sent. I see that the protocol allows me to get the refresh token any time I want by manipulating the AccessType and ApprovalPrompt. However, I am unable to figure out what api call allows me to do this.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, can you refer me to the documentation you're using?

Comment: I looked here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl To get control of the access_type and approval_prompt, I looked for methods in Google.Apis libraries. A previous version of the library seems to be able to do this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094599/google-analytics-oauth-with-accesstype-offline-in-c-sharp but I could not find similar methods in the 1.9

Comment: @peleyal I was wondering if you have any updates?

Answer (score 6):

I also had the exact same question. Credit goes to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094599/google-analytics-oauth-with-accesstype-offline-in-c-sharp). 
I will paste my code as I had to make a small change to get it working. 
(to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer in the constructor rather than AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer)

Implement your own GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow class and set the "offline" access in the AccessType property. This will give you the refreshtoken.

```
 public class OfflineAccessGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    {
        public OfflineAccessGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
        {
            return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
            {
                ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
                Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                AccessType = "offline",
                ApprovalPrompt = "force"
            };
        }
    };
```

It's unfortunate that we can't set the "access_type" from GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow Initializer.

Also, I use following code to retrieve the refresh token,

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse token = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse();
            //// Checks if the token is out of date and refresh the access token using the refresh token.
            if (result.Credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
            {
                //If the token is expired recreate the token
                token = await result.Credential.Flow.RefreshTokenAsync(userid.ToString(), result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken, CancellationToken.None);

                //Get the authorization details Results 
                result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
```