# Google Drive Api - MVC IDataStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using the MVC [sample code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications) from google to connect to Google Drive.
However I want to implement my own `IDataStore` so that I can keep user credentials inside my database.

With the FileStorage sample everything works fine and I get the **Token** and **RefreshToken** and more than that, it automatically refresh tokens when expired.

Implementing the `IDataStore` looks easy :

```
public class MyDataStore : IDataStore
{
    public Task ClearAsync()
    {
        ...
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        ...
    }

    public Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So in the `StoreAsync` I save the credentials on my database, and on the `GetAsync` I get it from the database.

But strangely when using this I receive the `access_token` but no `refresh_token` is returned from Google.

I've tried to search from samples using a custom `IDataStore` but I can't find anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you added "access_type=offline" in the authorization code request when you want the refresh_token?

Comment: Every time I call the api I don't receive any refresh token. I only receive the access_token filled. Not sure what do you mean. Thanks

Comment: UserCredential and AuthorizationCodeFlow take care of automatically "refreshing" the token, which simply means getting a new access token. This is done using a long-lived refresh token, which you receive along with the access token if you use the access_type=offline parameter during the authorization code flow. You may find the information on your sample code url.

Comment: @gui47 You led me into the right direction. I searched and found a solution to my issue. I will post it for future reference. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Glad to know you get what you want.

Comment: You really saved me. Otherwise I was already considering going manually with http calls. Thank YOU

Comment: Could you mark it as right answer? Appreciate it.

Comment: I can't because you replied with a comment and not an answer. Don't worry :)

Comment: Well I see, never mind. That's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking in account @gui47 comment I searched on how to add access_type parameter and I found out another [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094599/google-analytics-oauth-with-accesstype-offline-in-c-sharp/22098208#22098208) with the solution:

```
internal class OfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
{
    public OfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

    public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
    {
        return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
        {
            ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
            Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            AccessType = "offline",
            ApprovalPrompt = "force"
        };
    }
};
```

Thank you very much