# How to get a list of most popular pages from Google Analytics in Python (Django)?

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to access Google Analytics API using the code provided by their documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

```
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run


CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'client_secrets.json')
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = '%s is missing' % CLIENT_SECRETS
FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets('%s' % CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE,
)
TOKEN_FILE_NAME = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'analytics.dat')


def prepare_credentials():
    storage = Storage(TOKEN_FILE_NAME)
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

    return credentials


def initialize_service():
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = prepare_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    return build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)


def get_analytics():
   initialize_service()
```

But the problem is that this code opens a browser and asks a user to allow access to analytics service. Does anyone know how to access Google Analytics API (=obtain that token) without oauth2?

Comment: I'm not an expert in google analytics, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892625/201359) appears to solve a similar problem. The key insight: "You will indeed have to use a private key instead of an access token"

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thank you for your answer! the difference is that they use  an old version of API, that is already closed by Google, and the new one opens a browser window each time I try to access it, moreover it demands me to hace a view for oauth2 callback

Comment: Hmmm, then check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/kny9h4YzeHw) thread. Perhaps with [offline access](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382056/201359)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to authorize Google APIs. You are using [Web Server](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) mode that allows you to access Google Services on behalf of your client, but what you really want to use in this case are [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

First thing make sure the Analytics API Service is enabled for you Cloud Project in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Then go into [Google Cloud Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and create a new Service Account Client ID. This will give you a certificate file and a Service Account Email. That's all you need.

Here's an example of how to authenticate and instantiate the Analytics API.

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# Email of the Service Account.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '<some-id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = '/path/to/<public_key_fingerprint>-privatekey.p12'

def createAnalyticsService():
  f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  return build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
```

This will access your Google Analytics Account as user `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL`, so you have to go into Google Analytics and give this user access to your Analytics data.

Adapted from: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts

Answer (score 1):

As a result I've wrote a [blog post](http://axiacore.com/blog/how-get-list-most-popular-pages-google-analytics-python/) with a solution that worked for me:

```
import httplib2
import os
import datetime

from django.conf import settings

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# Email of the Service Account.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL ='12345@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

# Path to the Service Account's Private Key file.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(
    settings.BASE_DIR,
    '53aa9f98bb0f8535c34e5cf59cee0f32de500c82-privatekey.p12',
)


def get_analytics():
    f = file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        key,
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    )
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)

    end_date = datetime.date.today()
    # 30 days ago
    start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

    data_query = service.data().ga().get(**{
        'ids': 'ga:123456',  # the code of our project in Google Analytics
        'dimensions': 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
        'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews',
        'start_date': start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        'end_date': end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        'sort': '-ga:pageviews',
    })
    analytics_data = data_query.execute()
    return analytics_data
```